# How to draw a graph on a very large dataset?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a file containing more than 10,000 lines. Each line contains data for different clusters. The data are some integer numbers. My file is looking like as follows:

```
1   2
5
4   6   10
43  23  28  55
12
32  51
56  39  90
98  41  
9
.........
.........
```

All the numbers are unique in the file. The number of data in every cluster may be different. This file is an output of a clustering algorithm. Now I have to draw a graph on these data. If the file contains not more than 50,000 unique data, this file can be given as input to matlab for drawing a graph. But my file has more than 2,00,000 unique data. So, matlab displays an error message as follows:

```
"Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options"
```

There is a possible solution that I can use sparse matrix. But the file is automatically created by a tool of the cluster algorithm. So there is no any option to export the output as the content of a sparse matrix. 
So, I need an idea how to draw a graph on such huge data. Instead of matlab, is there any other software (either Linux based or Windows based) to solve my problem? I wrote a matlab script like as follows:

```
clc;
m=dlmread('C:\Users\Dhan\Desktop\clusteredResult_demo.txt');
plot(m);
```

Comment: 2.000.000 datapoints, stored in uint16 is only `(2000000*2)/2^20 = 3.81 MB` so memory should not be a problem I would say. What do you do with the data? Where do you get this error?

Comment: I want to draw a graph on these values. When reading these values from the file, the error is occurred.

Comment: What do you pretend to see? the only way you'd be able to actually see your data is if your screen is 2.000.000 pixels wide. That is about 1000 normal screens one next to the other, and that is in the case where each data will be just one pixel. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: These points are the results of a clustering algorithm. The file has many clusters. Every line is a separate cluster. All the points are belong to those clusters. I want to draw a graph to show graphically which clusters have maximum number of data points.

Comment: If you only want to know how many datapoints are in your cluster you can use the `L` variable in the script below. For example only plot if L>4.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open your file using this script? With this script I can open a file with 10.000 lines in 0.234789 seconds using my PC.

```
tic
%open file
fid = fopen('file.txt');
%allocate memory
M=zeros(10000,6,'uint16');

%get data
l=fgetl(fid);
L=sum(l==' ')+1;
v=textscan(l,'%u16',L);
M(1,1:L)=v{:};ct=2;
l=fgetl(fid);
while ~isnumeric(l)
    L=sum(l==' ')+1;
    v=textscan(l,'%u16',L);
    M(1,1:L)=v{:};ct=ct+1;
    l=fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
toc
```

The problem is probably in the next steps. What do you do with all these values?

Comment: I believe OPs problem is the graphics engine running out of memory, not MATLAB per se

Comment: Can you please explain more? I cannot get your point. @AnderBiguri Biguri

Comment: He runs out of memory when he does `plot`, not when he loads the data. Because plot needs java, openGL and other things. `memory_data<memory_plot`

Comment: `pos=rand(2E6,2);tic;plot(pos(:,1),pos(:,2),'.');toc`
`>> Elapsed time is 0.016446 seconds.` So probably there is something wrong in the way he calls plot? Because plotting 2 million points is no problem for Matlab.

Comment: @Gelliant depends on the computer I assume.

Comment: I have 4 GB (2.93 usable) RAM, 2.27 GHz i3 processor with original windows 7 Home premium OS. Is it not enough for plotting? @AnderBiguri

Comment: @DhrubaJyotiBorah have you read the first cooment on your question?